# mongodb. C#. Can't save multi leveled model to db

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Can someone just explane how to save to mongodb multilevel models!
I understand that may be somewhere here i CAN find the answer but all i find here NOT work for me.

i have several models A, B, C, D, E:

- A
- _id
- some field
- B[]

  - _id
  - some field
  - C[]

    - _id
    - some field
    - D[]

      - _id
      - some field
      - E[]

        - _id
        - some field

First level saving is OK!
Second level saving is OK!
Third level i do like this:

```
        IMongoQuery query = Query.And(Query<A>.EQ(a => a.A_Id, data.A_Id),
            Query<A>.ElemMatch<Wall>(a => a.B, b => b.EQ(tt => tt.B_Id, data.B_Id)));

        var update = Update.Push("B.$.C", data.C.ToBsonDocument());
        collection.Update(query, update);
```

Seems working;

But how can i save/update next levels?

Fourth level i try to save like this:

```
        var query = Query.And(Query<A>.EQ(a => a.A_Id, data.A_Id),
            Query<A>.ElemMatch(a => a.B, bb => bb.EQ(tt => tt.B_Id, data.B_Id)),
            Query<B>.ElemMatch(b => b.C, c => c.EQ(wm => wm.C_Id, data.C_Id)));
        var update = Update.Push("C.$.D", data.D.ToBsonDocument());
        collection.Update(query, update);
```

May be someone can explain to me HOW correctly write queries using C# Driver. Or i'm too stuped and do everything wrong!

Comment: Why don't you use collection.Save?

Comment: Cause Update will save or update model. besides it works fine on on first 3 levels.

Comment: save also saves or updates the document.

Answer (score 0):

Work like this but njt correct:

```
var query = Query.And(Query<A>.EQ(item => item.A_Id, data.A_Id),
   Query<A>.ElemMatch<B>(t => t.B, t => t.EQ(tt => tt.B_Id, data.B_Id)),
   Query<A>.ElemMatch<Wall>(t => t.B, t => t.ElemMatch<C>(tt => tt.C, tt =>
   tt.EQ(ttt => ttt.C_Id, data.C_Id))));

var update = Update.Push("B.0.C.$.D", data.D.ToBsonDocument());

collection.Update(query, update);
```